# Anosim problems with grouping

Tags: r, vegan

I have a simple table.

```
  Station Species_Richness Total_Abundance Species_Evenness Species_Diversity
    <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>
       1               56          223.              0.470             0.730
       2               51          193.              0.578             0.856
       3               41          132.              0.472             0.737
       4               37           63.4             0.259             0.362
       5               23            8.62            0.712             0.852
       6               21           47.5             0.329             0.483
       7               14            9.14            0.510             0.626
```

When I try and run
`anosim<-anosim(MyData_grouped, Station, permutations = 999)`

I get this error "Error in is.factor(x) : object 'station' not found" I have tried changing my groups to Station1, Station2, etc in the hope it wanted a non-numeric variable, and still nothing. What am I messing up? I am trying to follow along with my professor's code and it's proving difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the grouping column from the `x`.  As there was only a single replication for group, here, we are replicating the rows with `rbind`

```
library(vegan)
df1 <- rbind(MyData_grouped, MyData_grouped)
anosim(df1[-1], df1$Station, permutations = 999)
```

-output

```
Call:
anosim(x = df1[-1], grouping = df1$Station, permutations = 999) 
Dissimilarity: bray 

ANOSIM statistic R:     1 
      Significance: 0.001 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999
```